# Python - Two player dice game

Tags: python

Using Pythons random number generator, 2 players rolls two dice and generates the score (formula in play_game function). Prompt both players and their names, as well as their score.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
p1 = input("What is player one's name? ")
p2 = input("What is player two's name? ")
print(f"Player 1 got {randint(1, 6)}")
print(f"Player 2 got {randint(1, 6)}")
```

This will do what you want.
Output would be:

```
>>>Player 1 got <number>
>>>Player 2 got <number>
```